# Does Sylvok Lifestaff work with Bronze Bombshell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I use [Endless Whispers](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=false&multiverseid=50129) to gift a [Bronze Bombshell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=107327) to my opponent.  Do I have enough time to equip a [Sylvok Lifestaff](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=207857) that I already have on the field to the Bronze Bombshell before the opponent sacrifices it, so that I can gain 3 life from Sylvok Lifestaff's second ability?

For reference, Endless Whispers' rules text reads: 'Each creature has "When this creature dies, choose target opponent. That player puts this card from its owner's graveyard onto the battlefield under their control at the beginning of the next end step."'  Bronze Bombshell has the ability: 'When a player other than Bronze Bombshell's owner controls it, that player sacrifices it. If the player does, Bronze Bombshell deals 7 damage to the player.'

And Sylvok Lifestaff has the relevant ability: 'Whenever equipped creature dies, you gain 3 life.'

Comment: Is Endless Whispers and Bronze Bombshell not enough combo for you?  Throw in a repeatable sac outlet, like Ashnod's Altar, and you get to deal an opponent 7 damage on each player's turn (and potentially more in multiplayer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have enough time (since equipping is done 'at sorcery speed'), but it doesn't really matter; you can only equip a creature *you control*:

> 02.6a Equip is an activated ability of Equipment cards. "Equip [cost]" means "[Cost]: Attach this permanent to target creature you control. Activate this ability only any time you could cast a sorcery."

Answer (score 1):

No. You can equip the [Sylvok Lifestaff](https://scryfall.com/card/som/209/sylvok-lifestaff) before the [Bronze Bombshell](https://scryfall.com/card/dis/160/bronze-bombshell) dies when you control it. When an opponent gains control of [Bronze Bombshell](https://scryfall.com/card/dis/160/bronze-bombshell) there is no chance for you to equip [Sylvok Lifestaff](https://scryfall.com/card/som/209/sylvok-lifestaff), because you can only equip creatures you control. You can gain 3 life when the [Bronze Bombshell](https://scryfall.com/card/dis/160/bronze-bombshell) first dies, but not 6 life.

Answer (score 0):

When Bronze Bombshell enters play under your opponent's control its ability will immediately trigger.  That ability will go on the stack when someone gets priority  (which happens immediately after the Endless Whispers trigger finishes resolving) at which point you will have the opportunity to play spells and activate abilities before it resolves  (since the sacrifice is part of the effect and not a cost, it won't happen until the ability resolves).

But you are limited to instants and instant speed abilities, and equipping can only be done whenever you could cast a sorcery (your turn, main phase, with nothing on the stack), and you can't equip creatures your opponent controls anyways.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have enough time to equip a Sylvok Lifestaff that I already have on the field to the Bronze Bombshell before the opponent sacrifices it

Yes. And that time is before your opponent gains control of Bronze Bombshell. You can equip Blond Bombshell while you control it, then if it dies your opponent gains control of Blond Bombshell, while you remain the controller of Sylvok Lifestaff, and since you are the controller, you are the "you" in "you gain 3 life."